# Text alignment in a Matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am trying to right-align the entries in a matplotlib axes legend (by default they are left-aligned), but can't seem to find any way of doing this. The setup I have is below:

(I have added data and labels to my_fig axes using the ax.plot() command)

```
ax = my_fig.get_axes()[0]
legend_font = FontProperties(size=10)
ax.legend(prop=legend_font, num_points=1, markerscale=0.5)
```

There is a list of legend keyword arguments in the docs for [matplotlib Axes](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html), but there doesn't seem to be any straighforward way to set the alignment of the legend entries there. Anybody know of a backdoor way of doing this? Thanks.

EDIT:

To clarify what I am trying to achieve, right now my legend looks like:

> ```
> Maneuver: 12-OCT-2011 12:00 UTC 
>
> Bias: 14-OCT-2011 06:00 UTC
> ```

I want it to look like:

> ```
> Maneuver: 12-OCT-2011 12:00 UTC 
>
>     Bias: 14-OCT-2011 06:00 UTC
> ```

Comment: Does your label text include multi-lines? If so you can use label_text.set_multialignment('right')

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. For the labels, I have a brief description and date. So right now, the legend has the descriptions stacked and aligned on the left, what I would like is for all the dates to be stacked (aligned on the right). I've edited my main message with an illustration.

Comment: As a workaround, you could pad them with spaces (provided you're using monospace font)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The backdoor you're looking for is the following:

```
# get the width of your widest label, since every label will need 
# to shift by this amount after we align to the right
shift = max([t.get_window_extent().width for t in legend.get_texts()])
for t in legend.get_texts():
    t.set_ha('right') # ha is alias for horizontalalignment
    t.set_position((shift,0))
```

Comment: Shout out! Just realized that you are the Paul I met at the IPython sprint at PyCon this year. I'm finally getting around to coding up this answer, thanks!

Comment: For me, this leads to "RuntimeError: Cannot get window extent w/o renderer".

EDIT: Alright, this can be fixed via "renderer = fig.canvas.get_renderer()", and then passing the renderer to "get_window_extent()"

Answer (score 27):

I tried to get the example work, but I couldn't.

At least since matplotlib version 1.1.1 (maybe earlier) we need a dedicated renderer instance.
Take care of your backend which defines the renderer. Depending on backend the output may look fine on screen but dismal as PDF.

```
# get the width of your widest label, since every label will need 
#to shift by this amount after we align to the right
renderer = figure.canvas.get_renderer()
shift = max([t.get_window_extent(renderer).width for t in legend.get_texts()])
for t in legend.get_texts():
    t.set_ha('right') # ha is alias for horizontalalignment
    t.set_position((shift,0))
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer of @Paul Ivanov took me into the right direction. But it needed a slight adaptation for me:

```
max_shift = max([t.get_window_extent().width for t in legend_obj.get_texts()])
for t in legend_obj.get_texts():
    t.set_ha('right')  # ha is alias for horizontalalignment
    temp_shift = max_shift - t.get_window_extent().width
    t.set_position((temp_shift, 0))
```

The change means that we set a different shift for each object based on its own width and the max width of the legend text.

For those that get the `Cannot get window extent w/o renderer` error, add a `plt.pause(0.1)` :)