# Vertical alignment of matplotlib legend labels with LaTeX math

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

When mixing labels that have subscripts with labels without them, they do not vertically align properly in the legend. Since matplotlib determines bounding boxes internally based on printing characters, using a `vphantom` character does not work to align these legend labels, and I have not had any luck changing the vertical alignment of the labels with `set_va`, either.

Below is a MWE that illustrates problem I am trying to solve. I would like the labels to align to the text baseline if at all possible, otherwise to the text top.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
plt.plot(x, np.random.uniform(size=(10,)), c='red', label=r'test')
plt.scatter(x, np.random.uniform(size=(10,)), c='blue', label=r'test${}_{xy}$')
plt.legend(ncol=2)                                                                          
plt.show()
```

[image: mwe image]

Comment: Could you add a picture which illustrates the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @DavidG, it's been added

Comment: Interesting.. I cannot reproduce this. What version of Python and matplotlib are you using?

Comment: @DavidG, I'm using Python 2.7.6, matplotlib 1.5.3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the `text.latex.preview` parameter to `True`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preview'] = True
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
plt.plot(x, np.random.uniform(size=(10,)), c='red', label=r'test')
plt.scatter(x, np.random.uniform(size=(10,)), c='blue', label=r'test${}_{xy}$')
plt.legend(ncol=2)                                                      

plt.show()
```

[image: Image with baseline-aligned labels]

For the effect of the `preview` argument, also refer to [this example](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.2/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/usetex_baseline_test.html).

Comment: Note: `text.latex.preview` was deprecated in matplotlib 3.3.0; see [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/usetex_baseline_test.html) for some more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look on [Text alignment in a Matplotlib legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936034/text-alignment-in-a-matplotlib-legend).

Or you can just shift down the second legend text,

```
h_legend = plt.legend(ncol=2)
y_shift = -2.5
h_legend.texts[1].set_position((0, y_shift))
```

You can peak your shift distance based on the extent of the legend window using something like:

```
h_legend = plt.legend(ncol=2)    
renderer = plt.gcf().canvas.get_renderer()
y_shift = -0.2*h_legend.texts[0].get_window_extent(renderer).height
h_legend.texts[1].set_position((0, y_shift))
```

this will shift the second text by 20% of the full legend window height.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @hashmuke. I'm curious, though, whether there's a way to automate shifting the labels, as my actual use case has many labels which may change over time.