# Set a label's position in a pylab legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just started learning python, so if the code isn't really appropriate, please let me know.

I got a fraction in a plot's legend. But since the position of the label didn't change, it looks quite weird:
[image: Plot example]

My code concerning this plot is the following:

```
datalist = [(np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=1), label) for filename,label in list_of_files]

for data, label in datalist:
pylab.errorbar(abs(data[:,0]), abs(data[:,3]), yerr = data[:,4], fmt = 'o', label=r'$\frac{U_1+U_2}{2}$')

legend = pylab.legend(loc = 2, numpoints = 1)
frame = legend.get_frame()
frame.set_facecolor('0.95')
pylab.xlabel(r'I$\,$[$\mathrm{\mu}$A]')
pylab.ylabel('U [V]')
pylab.ylim([0,0.1])
pylab.show()
```

I used the scope because there will be more values from different files in the plot, I just wanted to fix the label's position before adding the other data.

How can I change the position of the label in the legend?

Comment: What is your `matplotlib` version? I do get the label centered correctly for 1.4.2

Comment: I have the matplotlib version 1.3.1. So maybe I should update it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical alignment of matplotlib legend labels with LaTeX math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424249/vertical-alignment-of-matplotlib-legend-labels-with-latex-math)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like the below. Found it on another answer on stackoverflow!

```
# Create legend
plt.plot(x, y, label = 'label_name')
leg = plt.legend( loc = 'upper right')

plt.draw() # Draw the figure so you can find the positon of the legend. 

# Get the bounding box of the original legend
bb = leg.get_bbox_to_anchor().inverse_transformed(ax.transAxes)

# Change to location of the legend. 
xOffset = 1.5
bb.x0 += xOffset
bb.x1 += xOffset
leg.set_bbox_to_anchor(bb, transform = ax.transAxes)


# Update the plot
plt.show()
```

Go here for more information: [Move and resize legends-box in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238041/move-and-resize-legends-box-in-matplotlib)