# How do we align marker and text in legends vertically in Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

When the marker in a legend is a dot, dot and text are not aligned vertically. To solve this I tried following:

```
l = ax.legend()
for text in l.texts:
    text.set_va('center') # Is there some setting for this in matplotlibrc, too??

plt.show()
```

The vertical alignment of text in a legend seems to be `baseline`. But no matter whether I choose `center`, `bottom` or `baseline`, etc., things are off:
[image]

Zooming in, this is what `Matplotlib` gives us out of the box:
[image]

What I want is also what other software like Inkscape gives me, when **aligning two objects vertically**:
[image]

Can `Matplotlib` do this for me/us?

Comment: Perhaps be more specific about what you mean by “properly”.  Why are you manually setting the vertical alignment at all?

Comment: pls provide some data for others to reproduce your result, then others can contribute.

Comment: [Looks like this is simply the default behaviour](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-with-legend-py): When marker in legend is a dot, the text's baseline is above the dot's.

Comment: The markers are not typeset - they are signed in a box that knows nothing about the text in the text box.  It’s not clear what behaviour you want, but I don’t think it’s trivial to exactly align these elements in any particular way.

Comment: Because what Matplotlib gives us by default is really off I added an image, too...

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work:

- Set it to display only a single scatterpoint per legend entry by setting `scatterpoints=1` in the call to `legend()`
- Set the vertical offset of this point to `0` by setting `scatteryoffsets=[0]` in the call to `legend()`
- After creating the legend, iterate through its text labels and set their vertical alignment to `center_baseline`, using `for t in l.get_texts(): t.set_va('center_baseline')`

```py
figure(figsize=(2,2))
scatter([0],[0],marker='s',s=20,label='Thing 1')
scatter([1],[0],marker='s',s=20,label='t')
scatter([2],[0],marker='s',s=20,label='T¹₁')
l = legend(scatterpoints=1,scatteryoffsets=[0],handletextpad=-0.5)
for t in l.get_texts(): t.set_va('center_baseline')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do:

```py
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\usepackage{amsmath}'
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex = True)
from matplotlib import pyplot as py

## setup figure
figure = py.figure(figsize = (7.5, 5.0))
axs = [py.subplot(1, 1, 1)]

## make plot
xs = np.linspace(0.0, np.pi, 100)
ys = np.sin(xs)
axs[0].plot(xs, ys, color = 'dodgerblue', label = r'$n = 1$')
ys = np.sin(2.0 * xs)
axs[0].plot(xs, ys, color = 'seagreen', label = r'$n = 2$')
axs[0].axhline(0.0, color = 'gray', linestyle = 'dashed')

## vertical alignment
legends = axs[0].legend(frameon = False, fontsize = 25, loc = 'lower left')
shift  = np.average([_.get_window_extent(renderer = figure.canvas.get_renderer()).height for _ in legends.get_texts()])
shift /= 3.6
for _ in legends.get_texts():
    _.set_va('center') ## va is alias for verticalalignment
    _.set_position((0, shift))

## save figure
name = 'test.pdf'
py.tight_layout()
py.savefig(name)
py.close()
```

It is, however, complicated and requires manual adjustments,
I am still looking for better solutions.

Comment: I learned it from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8078114/6037395).