# How to line up labels one above the other in a Matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, text-alignment

The code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, x+np.log10(2),  color = 'blue',  linestyle = ':', label = r'$ doubled \quad \bf{ y=2*x }$')
plt.plot(x, x-np.log10(2),  color = 'green', linestyle = ':', label = r'$ halved  \quad \bf{ y=0.5*x }$')
plt.legend(fontsize = 15)
```

produces a plot where the mathematical part of the second label `y=0.5*x` is shifted to the left relative to the mathematical part of the first label `y=2*x`; is it possible to modify something (automatically) so that both `y` start at exactly the same level?

Well, by "automatically" I mean some instruction/code that would avoid manually adding `\,` symbols in the second label, until the alignment works more or less well...

[image]

Comment: This is tricky to do with variable width fonts. You would need to pre-compute the width of each leading word. I suggest to use a monospace font as a quick and easy workaround.

Comment: this one can help u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936034/text-alignment-in-a-matplotlib-legend. Looks like they figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**In case it helps:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

texts = ['doubled', 'halved']
maxt = len(max(texts, key=len))

texts = [elem.ljust(maxt) for elem in texts]

plt.plot(x, x+np.log10(2),  color = 'blue',  linestyle = ':', 
         label = texts[0] + r'$ \quad \bf{ y=2*x }$')
plt.plot(x, x-np.log10(2),  color = 'green', linestyle = ':', 
         label = texts[1] + r'$ \quad \bf{ y=0.5*x }$')
plt.legend(prop={'family':'monospace', 'size': 16})
```

[image]